# Find all members of all classes/structs N bytes offset from the start of the class/struct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Ok this is kind of a complicated problem, I've been trying to track down a bug in a fairly large codebase for the past 4 months, that only happens on a platform where valgrind isn't available.

What's happening is that is a single byte, 0x01, is getting written in a weird spot (random when it happens, but it always seems to be written in a small collection of possible spots, regardless of debug/release or which compiler is used). I found out that the error byte is always 80 bytes away from the start of the object it corrupts.

Anyway, is there any tool or trick or plugin for visual studio that can scan the entire codebase and list all members that are 80 bytes offset from the start of their class?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a member that is at an 80 byte offset. It could easily be (and most likely is) a buffer overrun that writes that byte. Think `struct foo{ char arr[10]; void bar(){ arr[80] = 1; } };`.

Comment: its 80 bytes off from the start of a class not from the start of an array, if it was an array overrun or stack overflow i'd expect the bytes before and after the corrupted one to also be corrupt

Comment: In my `foo` example, `arr[80]` *is* at an 80 byte offset from the start of `foo`, because `arr` is at the same position as the start of foo.

Comment: its not the same class that gets corrupted every time though, but it always seems to be at +80

Answer (score 0):

If it's always in a consistent place, i.e. in a particular instance of a struct, you could put a break point once that instance has been initialised, then set a break point on the particular address which fires when the memory changes (I forgot the actual name for those break points in VS).

This is a really handy technique for finding that elusive screwy operation that writes to a location it shouldn't!

Comment: The bug happens if I continually trigger loads/unloads over and over again (at least, loads/unloads are when it will hard-crash, so if it happens between there I cant really tell), so the specific instance it happens is isnt always in the same spot in memory

Comment: This may sound stupid, but have you searched your code base for `80` and also for `20` (thinking 32-bit pointers, if you're on 64 bit try `10`). I once had a similar issue, if it's always a constant offset it would suggest pointer arithmetic on a bad pointer.

Comment: I have searched it for 80 already, I could try 20 and 10 too.

Comment: If those don't turn anything up, look for any areas where you're calculating an array index or doing pointer arithmetic, sounds like a large code base though!

Comment: yeah its up to about 50k lines of code so I can't really search it by hand :/